# Why multiple implementations not allowed declare as module service in module-info.java?

Tags: java, service, dependency-injection, module

I have one module that provides two implementations of a interface. I am getting compile error 'Duplicate service entry: org.util.hsm.api.HSMService'. Both of implementations belong to same module.

module-info.java

```
module org.util.thales.hsm {
    uses org.util.hsm.api.HSMService;
    provides org.util.hsm.api.HSMService with org.util.hsm.thales.ThalesHSMService;
    provides org.util.hsm.api.HSMService with org.util.hsm.safenet.SafeNetHSMService;
}
```

Comment: Autowiring injects the single implementation into the relevant context. If it has a choice of more than one, which should be regarded as the correct one?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I am not a spring guy. But as per my understanding. ServiceLoader.load(HSMService.class) returns Interator if implementations of HSMService.class so there should be no problem declaring multiple implementations of some service in same module.

Answer (score 10):

After a lot of trial and error, i found the solution.

```
module org.util.thales.hsm {
    uses org.util.hsm.api.HSMService;
    provides org.util.hsm.api.HSMService with org.util.hsm.thales.ThalesHSMService, org.util.hsm.safenet.SafeNetHSMService;
}
```